# Boost Graph Library: shortest cycle with resource constraints

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory

## Problem

In a directed graph with arbitrary arc lengths (travel times, costs) find the shortest (fastest, cheapest) cycle (or closed walk without repeated vertices). Or, alternatively, find the shortest cycle through a given vertex.

## Toward Solution

The [r_c_shortest_paths](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/r_c_shortest_paths.html) of [the Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) solves this exact question for... shortest paths.  The [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/example/r_c_shortest_paths_example.cpp) demonstrates its usage clearly.

Despite several attempted approaches it does not seam possible to efficiently use the r_c_shortest_paths for the problem described above.

## Question

Is it possible to use the r_c_shortest_paths to solve this problem? If so, how?

Another BGL algorithm?

Another C++ Graph library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to write something up, such as a complete traversal of the graph reachable from the origin (which may not be that bad or that hard), the path of least resistance here, especially considering your graph is directed, would probably be to just use `r_c_shortest_paths` on each of the origin's neighbors (in the sense of correct direction). Assuming one implementation it would be something like:

```
std::vector<Path<Nodes>> best_paths;
size_t first_step = -1;
for(auto&& [neighbor, weight] : boost::zip(origin.neighbors(), origin.weights())) {
    auto paths = r_c_shortest_paths(neighbor, origin);
    if(!paths.empty() && (best_paths.empty() || paths[0].cost + weight < best_paths[0].cost + first_step)) {
         best_paths = paths
         first_step = weight
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was thinking about a similar solution, but consider it sub optimal given the consecutive independent calls to r_c_shortest_path().

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the excellent Boost library has the solution, r_c_shortest_paths function is able to do exactly that... Just need to spend enough time on the documentation I guess.

**Cycles**

As can be seen from the pseudo code in the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/graph/doc/r_c_shortest_paths.html), the algorithm stops extending a path when the resource constraint or domination function hits. That the end-node was reached is checked in a next step. So using the same vertex as start and end allows for listing cycles.